# Docker could not pull kubernetes related images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Docker could not pull kubernetes related images
(gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64,gcr.io/google_containers/kube-controller-manager-amd64,gcr.io/google_containers/kube-scheduler-amd64,gcr.io/google_containers/kube-proxy-amd64,gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64 etc while installing kubernetes master(kubeadm init} and worker(kubeadm join).

Unsetting the proxy didn't work.

Can anyone suggest, what might be the issue.

Comment: What is the error? Any details? Didn't work can mean 100 different things. Always post details as much as possible if you want people to be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Where are you from?
If you come from China, many mirror can use in mainland.
etc. AliCloud